# Get current time (and date) WITHOUT opening a subshell

Tags: bash, shell, date, subshell

Is it possible to get current time ( and possibly date ) without doing it via a subshell?

because if I'm not mistaken, this command do open a subshell?

```
d=$(date)
```

Comment: cat /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/time cat /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/date

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With Bash≥4.2 you can use `printf` with the `%(datefmt)T` format:

```
printf '%(%c)T\n' -1
```

`-1` means *now.*

See [The Bash reference at the `printf` entry](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-printf).

To put it in a variable (and hence not use a subshell):

```
printf -v d '%(%c)T' -1
echo "$d"
```